# How to replace the content between two flags using regular expressions in Android?

Tags: java, android, regex

I set two flags for a text string, I hope to replace all the content between the flag `<!--BeginOfReplace-->` and the flag `<!--EndOfReplace-->`.

I think the regular expressions can do it, how can I write a code in Java? Thanks!

**Text String**

```
This is a cup

<!--BeginOfReplace-->     

   Hello, world !

<!--EndOfReplace--> 

I will go back.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is great library call jsoup.Jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods. Great tutorial = > https://inducesmile.com/android/android-html-parser-using-jsoup-tutorial/

```
String html = "<p>An <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b>  </a> link.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
  Element link = doc.select("a").first();
```

thats an example, can you work from there.

Comment: in your case it is a div, the inner one that is.

Comment: Thanks! I hope to  replace all content between two flags with Java

Comment: sure your welcomed , i you have inquiries just ask.

Comment: And more, all content include  <div id="Div1">    Hello, world !    </div> should be replace!

Comment: yea just search for all div, it will return all elements go give it a shot.just gave you a up vote.!

Comment: Thanks! I think maybe it's better to use regular expression in java because I have set two flags

Comment: Either way works, jsoup supports regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks! I think jsoup is too slow

Comment: alright do you accept the answer then , want me to restructure it?

Comment: To Caspain Caldion: could you give me a regular expressions solution ? Thanks!